# Jquery Ajax post success/error function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement the following code, which run successfully, but blows right through the success function. I put an alert in there which shows only for an instant, but the following jquery message call does not appear. (message function works in other instances on the same page).

Using jquery 1.6.

Any idea why the code is not executing as it should? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#postride').submit(function() {

     dataString = $("#postride").serialize();
     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "postride.php",
        data:dataString,
        error: function() {
            alert('error!');
            $(".message").text('An error occurred');
            $(".message").fadeIn("slow");
            $(".message").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);    
        },
        success: function () {
            alert('success!');
            $(".message").text('Your post has been completed');
            $(".message").fadeIn("slow");
            $(".message").delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);    
            setTimeout( function() { top.location.href="view.php" }, 3000 );    
        }
     })
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `#postride` is a form which you are posting using `ajax`. The problem in your code is you are not stopping the default behavior of the form to submit. As soon as you submit the form is post before ajax call response comes and you hardly see anything.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#postride').submit(function(e) {
     //This line will prevent the form from submitting
     e.preventDefault();


     dataString = $("#postride").serialize();
     $.ajax({

...  
     });

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood, you're not getting your .message to show the text?

[I made a jsfiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/bobbynorris/j6age/) and it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: Ahh... yes, like @ShankarSangoli says you need to stop the default action of the submit.